# How to test methods of an class that don't have parameters or returns in python using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest, pytest-mock

Let's say that I have a class, this class have some attributes and some methods. This methods don't have any parameters or any return, they only work by changing the attributes of the class using the 'self.' property. How can I test these types of methods?

Let's create the imaginary class Foo to serve as example:

```
class Foo:
     example_value = -1

     def function_1(self,a,b):
        self.attr1 = a
        self.attr2 = b

        self.function_2()
        self.function_3()
        self.function_4(self.example_value)


    def function_2(self):
        self.attr1 = self.attr1 + 50
        self.attr2 = self.attr2 + 40

    def function_3(self):
        self.attr1 = self.attr1 * 2
        self.attr2 = self.attr3 * 3
        self.example_value = self.attr1 + self.attr3

    def function_4(self,value):
        
        if value == -1:
            raise Exception('snippet')
```

In order to test this class, what should I mock? Since two of the methods don't have any input parameters or returns, how can I track the value change of the class attributes? Should I mock only a method or the entire class? And how can I do it in a simple way with `pytest`? What could be changed in this code? The addition of a simple `get_value()` would simplify the test development for this class?

Comment: Don't mock anything. Its a tool of last resort anyway. Just check how the attributes have been changed.

Comment: This code is too abstract to make any reasonable suggestions. Maybe there's a reason no method takes arguments or returns values. Maybe there's a reason all communication takes place via the instance attributes. But without knowing what the class is supposed to model or what purpose the methods serve, we can't say anything meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just verify the attributes, after the method being called, something like this:

```py
from unittest import TestCase


class TestFoo(TestCase):

    def test_f1(self):
        x = Foo()
        x.function_1(10, 20)
        self.assertEqual(x.attr1, 120)
        self.assertEqual(x.attr2, 30)
        self.assertEqual(x.attr3, 10)
        self.assertEqual(x.example_value, 130)

    def test_f4(self):
        try:
            Foo().function_4(1)
        except Exception:
            self.fail("function_4() raised Exception unexpectedly!")

    def test_f4_error(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            Foo().function_4(-1)
```

Comment: I think i was overcomplicating the things because i'm not too experienced in unit testing. This will probably be enough to help and guide me, Thank you. :D